# How to detect patterns in data stream?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to detect patterns (sequences) in data flow.
For example, we have a continuous stream of data, say, integers:

1 5 1 **9 9 9 0** 4 5 8 4 **9 9 9 0** 4 7 2 **9 9 9 0** 1 4 1

There is the pattern: **9 9 9 0**

I need to detect (catch) patterns (sequences) like this.
Are such tasks solved by ML?
Thanks!

PS: Used platform: net core

**EDIT:**
The fact is that I don’t know which patterns to look for. When initializing (setting), I can only set the pattern parameters (length, repeatability...).
I want algo to find some equals parts of data.
Somthing like "Change Point Detector" algo in ML.
Or somthing like "regular expression", but with data flow.

Comment: No, just read 4 values at a time and check their values. You didn't show any kind of *pattern* either, just 4 numbers that may or may not follow a pattern. In C# 7 you could use `Slice(i,4)` to read 4 items at a time without actually copying them into a new buffer

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm. The algorithm works by finding a word within a string. An example of the same is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm